# Array in Between Condition

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I implement this condition as shown in this image.
[image]

Comment: what do you mean how to implement this condition? in an if-else statement?

Comment: The ≥ and ≤ are shown by IntelliJ just to visualize a range is involved. The range itself does not have them in its representation, it's just `2..4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just `in 2..4`, i.e. *in the integer range from 2 to 4, including the 4*.

The `≤` is just some hint text provided by the IDE, similar to how you can see argument names in function calls - it's not part of the code, it's not really *there*. They added it to make it clearer what the `..` operator does (vs `until`)

This might be because [they're introducing a new operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#preview-of-the-operator-for-creating-open-ended-ranges), `..<` which seems intended to replace `until`, or maybe they've been there a while! You can turn them on and off here in the settings:

[image: A screenshot of the settings option to enable/disable these hints]